# SQL Query on Aggregating the sequence numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a table which has sequence numbers from 1 to 90000
so i wanted to know how to automatically assign the values to the sequence numbers 
say for example from 1 to 1000 i want them to fall under 1000 bucket 
from 1001 to 2000 under 2000 bucket 
and so on up to 90000 records.

Comment: Are you referring to a SQL Server `SEQUENCE` object - or just a consecutive series of numeric values in rows?

Comment: I have field named as sequence in which i have the values as 1,2 ....90000,so for that values i want data to be assigned in groups like 1 to 1000 should fall under 1000 and 1001 to 2000 should fall under 2000 and so on,

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Think about this from somebody else's perspective. It just doesn't make any sense what you want to do here.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the number by 1000, floor it, and multiply it back by 1000:

```
SELECT   1000*FLOOR(num/1000) + 1, COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY FLOOR(num/1000)
```

Comment: I dont think this is what I am looking for, i want it this way Mureinik from 1 to 1000 they should be shown as 1000, from 1001 to 2000 it should be 2000 and so on upto 90000,

Comment: @sweety I had an off-by-one error which I edited and fixed. If that's not what you mean, can you please edit your question and add the actual result so it would be clearer?

Comment: select * from function(1,1000,1000)
union all 
select * from fucntion(1001,2000,2000)   here first value is the starting point, 2nd value is the ending point, and the third value is the number of items in the bucket. I want it till 90000

Answer (score 1):

The [Modulo (%)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql) operator is perfect for something like this...
So easy, it feels like it's cheating.

```
WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)), 
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),
    cte_n3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b),
    Sequense (n) AS (
        SELECT TOP 90000
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM
            cte_n3 a CROSS JOIN cte_n3 b
        )
SELECT 
    SequenseNumber = s.n, 
    GroupNumber = s.n - (s.n % 1000)
FROM
    Sequense s;
```

Results...

```
SequenseNumber       GroupNumber
-------------------- --------------------
1                    0
2                    0
3                    0
4                    0
5                    0
6                    0   
.........................   
997                  0
998                  0
999                  0
1000                 1000
1001                 1000
1002                 1000
1003                 1000
1004                 1000
1005                 1000
1006                 1000
1007                 1000
1008                 1000
1009                 1000
1010                 1000
.........................
89990                89000
89991                89000
89992                89000
89993                89000
89994                89000
89995                89000
89996                89000
89997                89000
89998                89000
89999                89000
90000                90000

(90000 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what you want, it uses [CEILING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql) and an algorithm that works from 0 to 90K literally consider that the **num** must be **DECIMAL** if you use int the decimal round is set to 0.

Test data

```
declare @tbl table(num decimal)
insert into @tbl
select 1 union
select 999 union
select 1000 union
select 1001 union
select 2001 union
select 3001 union
select 9999 union
select 10000 union
select 10001 union
select 15001 union
select 25001 union
select 77006 union
select 80000 union
select 90000
```

Query

```
SELECT distinct
num,
CASE WHEN num <= 10000 THEN 1000*CEILING(num/1000)
     WHEN num <= 20000 THEN 10000 + 1000*CEILING((num-10000)/1000)
     WHEN num <= 30000 THEN 20000 + 1000*CEILING((num-20000)/1000)
     WHEN num <= 40000 THEN 30000 + 1000*CEILING((num-30000)/1000)
     WHEN num <= 50000 THEN 40000 + 1000*CEILING((num-40000)/1000)
     WHEN num <= 60000 THEN 50000 + 1000*CEILING((num-50000)/1000)
     WHEN num <= 70000 THEN 60000 + 1000*CEILING((num-60000)/1000)
     WHEN num <= 80000 THEN 70000 + 1000*CEILING((num-70000)/1000)
     WHEN num <= 90000 THEN 80000 + 1000*CEILING((num-80000)/1000)
     ELSE 0
     END
FROM     @tbl
```

Result

```
1       1000
999     1000
1000    1000
1001    2000
2001    3000
3001    4000
9999    10000
10000   10000
10001   11000
15001   16000
25001   26000
77006   78000
80000   80000
90000   90000
```

Comment: @sweety, good to know it helped, please mark it as the correct answer so we help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that what Jason posted is what the OP is looking for. This is a slight variation using [getnumsAB](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Set+Based/139370/) which was developed for exactly this type of thing. First we'll use it to create some sample data:

**Sample data**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#yourdata') is not null drop table #yourdata;
select SequenceNumber = rn
into #yourdata
from dbo.GetNumsAB(1,90000,1,1);
create unique clustered index uq_cl_yourdata on #yourdata(SequenceNumber);
```

To understand my solution first note this query:

```
select rn, n1, n2 from dbo.getnumsAB(0,90000,1000,1);
```

This returns:

```
rn    n1       n2
----- -------- --------
1     0        1000
2     1000     2000
3     2000     3000
4     3000     4000
.... 
87    86000    87000
88    87000    88000
89    88000    89000
90    89000    90000
```

**Solution**

```
select y.SequenceNumber, GroupNumber = n1
from #yourdata y
join dbo.getnumsAB(0,90000,1000,1) gn 
  on y.SequenceNumber >= n1 and y.SequenceNumber < n2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not missing something wouldn't you just use a case statement?

select case
           when Sequence <= 1000
           then '1000'
           when Sequence <= 2000 and >= 1001
           then '2000'

and so on up to 9000?

Comment: select case when Sequence <= 1000 then '1000' when Sequence <= 2000 and Sequence  >= 1001 then '2000'